# How do I sort the keys in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the stage key in ascending order.
I want this order: `{'stage_1','stage_2','stage_3','stage_11','stage_22'}`

```
let data = {
    "stage_1": "PADIYANALLUR",
    "stage_11": "Weels India Rd.Jn.",
    "stage_2": "GUINDY TVK I.E",
    "stage_22": "RED HILLS",
    "stage_3": null,
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?  The data returned will be the same regardless of the order of the keys, so it may be that you're using an object when you *should* be using an array.

Comment: @JomiMoses do you want the `object sorted by key` or `just the sorted keys` ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, i just want to sorted keys

Comment: @JomiMoses hasn't jo_va aswered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Objects in JavaScript do not guarantee key ordering. You have to use arrays.**

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to produce an ordered array of keys.

To order numerically based on the number suffix in your key, use [`+key.match(/\d+/)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to extract the digits and convert them to a number:

```js
const data = {
  "stage_1": "PADIYANALLUR",
  "stage_11": "Weels India Rd.Jn.",
  "stage_2": "GUINDY TVK I.E",
  "stage_22": "RED HILLS",
  "stage_3": null,
};

const result = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => +a.match(/\d+/) - +b.match(/\d+/));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This maps into an array of array

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee, this is to keep the key/values together

Comment: the OP wants a sorted object by key value, you are returning him a  array of array

Comment: @ Kunal Mukherjee, a sorted object does not exist in JS

Comment: Should the last example return `stage_1`, then `stage_2` as OP wants the order ascending?

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee, no it won't, since you will get stage_1, stage_11, stage_2, you have to extract the digits and compare them as numbers

Comment: Ultimately you're going to end up having to store your sorted items into an array reference or a `Map` - Ordering the keys of an Object does not exist.

`new Map(result.map(key => [key, data[key]] ))`